# Play Protect Appeals - Blocked By Play Protect - SHA256 Hash

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-product-search

I was opening the form and registering my application in Google Product to avoid being blocked.
In the past, it was enough to put a simple direct download link of the application in this section.
But now it wants a link in the format `SHA256 Hash of the apk of the uploaded file on Virus Total` !!

If you are familiar with making this type of link, guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking various things, I found a way to get the hash code.
It is as simple as this word!

Just go to the main page of `https://www.virustotal.com/` and upload your file.
And in the next step, enter the details section and **copy the hash code**.